# Android Material Seekbar increase thum size

Tags: android

I have created a style that extends the material seekbar in android to make the `horizontal` bar thicker I would also like to increase the size of the thumb that is dragged. I don't want to change the thumb just use the normal `@drawable/scrubber_control_material_anim.`

Comment: https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar
I use that library, and it is very simples to use, maybe it can help you xD

Comment: @LucasPaolillo there is no way to do it without the need to use external libraries?